# Redux saga function not running on very first try

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

So, whenever i start my server. I dont why but my saga function is not working while logging in. I have ensured that action was running. Also, once i reload the page it starts working.

here is how i am setting my watcher.

```
export function* watchUserLogin() {
  console.log("login");
  yield takeEvery(LOGIN_USER, loginUser);
}

export function* watchUserLogout() {
  yield takeEvery(LOGOUT_USER, logoutUser);
}

function* authSaga() {
  yield all([fork(watchUserLogin), fork(watchUserLogout)]);
}
```

also my main saga function

```
function* loginUser({ payload: { user, history } }) {
  try {
    console.log("login");
    const response = yield call(Login, user.email, user.password);
    console.log(response, "ah");
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
      const user = yield response.data;

      sessionStorage.setItem("authUser", JSON.stringify(user));
      console.log(user);
      var decoded = jwt_decode(user.access);
      yield put(loginSuccess(user));
      if (decoded.is_preferences) {
        history.push("/dashboard");
        // const session = yield call(checkSession);
        // console.log(session);
        console.log(sessionStorage.getItem("authUser"));
      } else {
        history.push("/preferences");
        // const session = yield call(checkSession);
        // console.log(session);
      }
    } else {
      throw response;
    }
    yield put(loginSuccess(user));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.response.status);
    yield put(loginFail(error.response.data, error.response.status));
  }
}
```

Comment: Hope you have instantiated sagaMiddleware and registered sagas in index.js file.

Comment: yes, I have initialized it above DOM render

Comment: I didn't get you. I suppose you should export authSaga function and register in createSagaMiddleware function of 'redux-saga' like createSagaMiddleware().run(authSaga). Can you paste the code where you are registering the saga to  middleware or store?

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
function* authSaga() {
  yield all([watchUserLogin(), watchUserLogout()]);
}
```

Also an example of connecting the saga

```
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

import { rootReducer } from './reducers';
import { rootSaga } from './saga';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware),
);

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

export { store };
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `takeLatest()` from Redux-saga effects for this answer (the other saga methods are fine aswell, you should have a look at the saga effects to find out which effect matches your use case) You would add this under your saga methods:

```
export function* loginUser({ payload: { user, history } }) {
...
}

export const authSaga = [
 takeLatest(LOGIN_USER, loginUser),
 takeLatest(LOGOUT_USER, logoutUser)
]
```

Import this saga in your rootSaga or create one if you are missing this:

```
export function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([
        ...authSaga
    ]);
}
```

Add this rootSaga where you configure your redux store and apply middleware:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { reducers } from "../core/state";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
import { routerMiddleware } from "connected-react-router";
import { logger } from 'redux-logger';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { rootSaga } from "../core/state/rootSaga";
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

export const history = createBrowserHistory();

const configureStore = (initialState = {}) => {
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
  let middleware = [sagaMiddleware, routerMiddleware(history), thunk]
  const store = createStore(
    reducers(history),
    initialState,
    composeWithDevTools(
      applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    )
  );
  sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
  return store;
};

export default () => configureStore({});
```

Not all of the above code needs to be added, this is just an configStore example of a project of mine, for your case be sure to add the following line to your config:

```
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
```

What does `takeLatest()` do? :

Spawns a saga on each action dispatched to the Store that matches pattern. And automatically cancels any previous saga task started previously if it's still running.

Each time an action is dispatched to the store. And if this action matches pattern, takeLatest starts a new saga task in the background. If a saga task was started previously (on the last action dispatched before the actual action), and if this task is still running, the task will be cancelled.